# tkinter Treeview: pass variable from window in different module

Tags: python, tkinter

I have problem with returning a variable from custom pop-up, when the pop-up is in different .py file. As already answered on Stack Overflow, this can be solved with global variables. However this solution works only if all functions are in a single .py. Code representing the issue is following:

main.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import main_popups as main_popups

def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()   
    main_btn= Button(screen, text = "Press me")
    main_btn.pack()  
    main_btn.configure(command = pressed)

    screen.mainloop()

def pressed():
    main_popups.input_box(screen)
    print(output_variable)

main_screen()
```

main_popups.py:

```
def input_box(screen):
    global input_box_screen
    
    def btn_press():
        global output_variable
        output_variable = entry.get()
        input_box_screen.destroy()
        input_box_screen.update()
        print(output_variable)
        
    input_box_screen = Toplevel(screen)
    
    entry = Entry(input_box_screen)
    entry.pack()   
    btn = Button (input_box_screen, text = "Confirm")
    btn.pack()
    btn.configure(command = btn_press)     
    
    screen.wait_window(input_box_screen)
```

This raises error at `print(output_variable)`, as `output_variable` is not returned from `btn_press` in `main_popups.py`. My question is how to return the text from Entry in `main_popups.py` to `main.py`? I tried to `return(output_variable)` at the end of `def btn_press():`, but that does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you don't need global variable, just return `output_variable` at the end of `main_popups.input_box()`:

#### main.py

```py
from tkinter import *
import main_popups

def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    main_btn= Button(screen, text = "Press me")
    main_btn.pack()
    main_btn.configure(command = pressed)

    screen.mainloop()

def pressed():
    output_variable = main_popups.input_box(screen)
    print(output_variable)

main_screen()
```

#### main_popups.py

```py
from tkinter import *

def input_box(screen):
    output_variable = None

    def btn_press():
        nonlocal output_variable
        output_variable = entry.get()
        input_box_screen.destroy()
        input_box_screen.update()

    input_box_screen = Toplevel(screen)

    entry = Entry(input_box_screen)
    entry.pack()
    btn = Button (input_box_screen, text = "Confirm")
    btn.pack()
    btn.configure(command = btn_press)

    screen.wait_window(input_box_screen)

    return output_variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just import output_variable with `from main_popups import output_variable` after you executed main_popups.py (between line 14 and 15)

PS.: Maybe you shouldnt have used the tag tkinter, because its a very specific tag and you would have gotten a faster replie.

Comment: Both answers works perfectly, however never heard about this kind of approach, thank you as this may come handy in the future.